# Java Realm MissingLibraryException

Tags: java, android, realm

Keep getting the following error on the line where I `Realm.init(this)`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.app/uk.app.LoginActivity}: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so
```

Any suggestions on solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Well what device is this? What other native libraries are you using? There's clearly not enough info to answer this question.

Comment: Well, I really don't have much more to go on, this is what I have been given. I am pretty sure it's a Samsung A5. By native libraries, what do you mean? I will fill in once confirmed.

Comment: Any other libraries that bring in their own `.so` files.

Comment: I don't think so...